# Can a series be non absolutely convergent at point beyond its radius of absolute convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, absolute-convergence

Let $\sum a_nx^n$ be a series, where $a_n$'s are not necessarily positive & let $R>0$ be its radius of absolute convergence. Then for $x=r>R$,  $\sum |a_n|r^n$ will be divergent, but my question is,  can the series $\sum a_nr^n$ be convergent.

Please give me few examples.

Comment: No: *any* sort of convergence, either conditional or absolute, at $x = r$ implies absolute convergence on the entire interval $[0, r)$.

Comment: For $|x|>R$ what happens is that the general term of the series doesn't tend to zero. Therefore, convergence is impossible. The funny thing is that even some graduate students of mathematics forget that. The consequence of just memorizing the phrase that T.Bongers told you without revisiting its proof.

Comment: @T.Bongers But, my question is,  can the series be convergent beyond radius of absolute convergence.

Comment: And the answer, based on my comment, is *no*. If it were convergent at $r$, then the radius is at least $r$.